# How to apply a function to specified groups

Tags: r

I would like to plot according to data in certain groups. For example I have the following data

```
Chr            Value

chr1           0.44
chr1           5.4
chr1           4.5
chr2           3.33
chr3           6.66
chr3           2.1
chr3           4.3
```

I would like to create separate plots for each group (so one plot for chr1, one for chr2 etc). How can I do this? The overall aim is to try to use a plot for posterior probabilities- it plots out how likely a step change in the data is likely to be real. It is called `bcp`. The code to run it is just

```
 library(bcp)
 bcp.0 <- bcp(testdata) 
 plot.bcp(bcp.0).
```

So id like to look at step changes per chr.

I've tried the following:

```
df <- read.delim("~/Desktop/SequencingScripts/blabla/tbb.txt", header=TRUE)


df = df[order(df[[1]], df[[2]]),]
View(df)

lst <- split(df, df$chr)
bcp.lst <- bcp(df[,5])
lapply(lst, function(x) plot.bcp(bcp.lst))
```

but i just end up with no error but also no plot.

and if I try

```
lst <- split(df, df$chr)
bcp.lst <- bcp(lst)
lapply(lst, function(x) plot.bcp(bcp.lst))
```

I end up with the error:

```
> bcp.lst <- bcp(lst)

Error in { : 
  task 1 failed - "(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'"
```

Comment: What kind of plots are you thinking of?

Comment: Actually Im trying to use a plot for posterior probabilities- it plots out how likely a step change in the data is likely to be real. It is called bcp. The code to run it is just bcp.0 <- bcp(testdata)
  plot.bcp(bcp.0). So id like to look at step changes per chr

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. If you need to add clarifications, edit the question

Comment: And please add the package that you use for those plots.

Comment: the package is called bcp

Comment: I don't know this package, but most likely you can't use `ggplot2` here if that's a special kind of plot. You could try something like `lst <- split(testdata, testdata$Chr); lapply(lst, function(x) plot.bcp(bcp(x)))` although that may not be the usual way of creating plots..

Comment: The plotting is part of bcp so ggplot definitely is not useful here but thanks for suggesting anyway. I guess Im asking how I can apply the bcp function above to the dataset split up by chr so I get a plot per chr.

Comment: You are almost there, but you have to specify the column for bcp. So like `lapply(split(df, df$chr), function(i) plot(bcp(i[["value"]])))` or even more simply `aggregate(value ~ chr, data=df, FUN=function(i) plot(bcp(i)))`. Note this will quickly produce one plot after the other. I am not sure how to produce a layout of the plots - so you could see them all - as the code for `plot.bcp` calls `grid.newpage()` and pushes viewports throughout it.

Comment: Actually, if you want to have multiple plots on one page you can remove the `grid.newpage()` call  and redefine `plot.bcp` using `body(plot.bcp) <- body(plot.bcp)[-3]`. You can then use `grid.layout` and such to draw multiple plots.